# SQL Server not using unallocated space

Tags: sql-server

I have a production server with below nature:

**Version:** 
Microsoft SQL Server 2014 - 12.0.4100.1

**Situation:**

A new table is generated everyday to keep track of multiple events, say event A, B and C.

Everyday, we will remove event A from tables that are more than 1 month old.

So basically that table would claims an unused space based on the size of event A permanently, based on (total_pages - used_pages), I would like to make good use of this space, instead of wasted just like that.

**Current Solution:**

Currently, our solution was to rebuild the table right after every "cleaning".

So each table would only use the size it should, while releasing the size to database, called "unallocated space" (Please correct me if I'm wrong at this point), by using stored procedure "exec sp_spaceused".

**Problem:**

Here comes my problem, my assumption based on what I learned from net is that, unallocated space is space already claimed on harddisk, but has not been allocated to any objects yet, hence I believe on every new table creation, it uses the unallocated space, instead of claiming more harddisk space.

But here's what happened this couple days:

**On 5th September, sp_spaceused returns:**

database_size: 447053.75 MB, unallocated space: 58268.34 MB

**On 6th September, sp_spaceused returns:**

database_size: 450773.50 MB, unallocated space: 57360.52 MB

As I have like 58GB unallocated space left, why would sql server takes another 3GB of my HD space, while using only 1GB of the unallocated space?

Thanks for the assistance in advance.

Comment: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/e35356ea-a3ee-4ffe-82de-a536f8209026/whats-unallocated-space?forum=sqldatabaseengine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. database_size includes both data and **log** files.
2. use 'updateusage' option to make sure sp_spaceused returns up-to-date data when you investigate something like that
3. unallocated does not always mean 'released size to database'. If the data file is growing (autogrow), it increases 'unallocated' size

The formula is simple:

> database_size = reserved + unallocated space + log space

Comment: Thanks for the information Anton, the extra size was indeed log file size, the mdf file size on harddisk actually never increased.